# не получается загрузить файл (HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

springframework.version - 4.3.7.RELEASE
springsecurity.version - 4.2.2.RELEASE

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adminka</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
    @Bean(name="HelloWorld")
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewPdfResolver() {
    ResourceBundleViewResolver viewResolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    viewResolver.setBasename("views");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}

@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/locales/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
    resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(78643200);
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(78643200);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

}

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
```

WebApplicationInitializer

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(AppConfiguration.class);
    appContext.register(HibernateConfiguration.class);
    appContext.register(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    // UtF8 Charactor Filter.
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

    fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class FileController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
 return "Урааааа";
}
```

Comment: В браузере вот тут `action="${uploadFile}"` присутствует название приложения (например `localhost:8080/MYAPP/uploadFile`  или просто `localhost:8080/uploadFile`)?

Comment: просто localhost:8080/uploadFile

Comment: начинает принимать post только если убрать input с файлом и enctype="multipart/form-data" в html

Comment: У Вас опечатка в `multiPartResolver`, нужно `multipartResolver` т.е. `Part` с маленькой буквы, попробуйте это поменять.

Comment: не помогло, все равно такая же ошибка

Comment: Сделайте минимальный пример, чтоб можно было воспроизвести эту ошибку у себя. В текущем вопросе слишком мало информации.

Comment: Стоит только убрать enctype='multipart/form-data' и все работает замечательно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки файлов без отключения `csrf` есть 2 варианта.

Указывать в action этот параметр:

```
<form action="/uploadFile?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" 
method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form>
```

Или добавить фильтр обрабатывающий загрузку файла перед spring security:

```
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }
}
```

Взято с документации [spring-security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipart)

Answer (score 0):

Работает если в SecurityConfiguration отключить csrf

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
          .and().csrf().disable();
```